# Satori in NextJS - Turn SVG into PNG in a NodeJS Runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, next.js, buffer

I am trying to understand [satori](https://github.com/vercel/satori) and use it in my next.js api routes. (I cannot use the `vercel/og` package).

I have everything working, but the one thing that I don't understand is how to turn my `svg` image generated by satori into a `png`. In the docs it says:

```
If you want to render the generated SVG to another image format such as PNG, it would be better to use base64 encoded image data (or buffer) directly as props.src so no extra I/O is needed in Satori:

await satori(
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,..." width={200} height={300} />,
  // Or src={arrayBuffer}, src={buffer}
  options
)
```

[Link: https://github.com/vercel/satori#images](https://github.com/vercel/satori#images)

I don't really understand what this means?

So far, my nextjs api route (next 13) looks like this:

```
export async function GET(req, res) {
  let fontUrl = "/Users/anton/projects/new_test/src/app/assets/fonts/NotoSans/NotoSans-Bold.ttf"
  const fontArrayBuf = await fs.readFile(fontUrl)
 
  
  const svg = await satori(
    "<div style={{ color: red }}>hello, world</div>",
    {
      width: 600,
      height: 400,
      fonts: [
        {
          name: 'Noto Sans',
          data: fontArrayBuf,
          weight: 400,
          style: 'normal',
        },
      ],
    }
  );


  // this works, but here i struggle
  // i would like to:
  // 1. turn the svg above into a png
  // 2. return the png from my next api route

  return NextResponse.json({ data: "some response" })
}
```

I have tried using `resvg`, but I am getting an error that I don't have the correct loader configured. But also, it seems like png is possible with satori (as it seems to suggest in the docs I copy-pasted above), but I am just not able to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`@napi-rs/image`](https://image.napi.rs/), specifically, you are after:

```
const transformer = Transformer.fromSvg(svg);

return await transformer.png();
```

Here is a complete example taken from https://ray.run:

```
import { Transformer } from '@napi-rs/image';
import { readFile } from 'node:fs/promises';
import { dirname, join } from 'node:path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
import satori from 'satori';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

export const generateOpenGraphImage = async (contents: { title: string }) => {
  const svg = await satori(
    <div
      style={{
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        background: '#0E0E11',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        fontFamily: 'Outfit',
        height: '100%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        padding: '0 180px',
        width: '100%',
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          color: '#fff',
          fontSize: 40,
          fontWeight: 400,
          letterSpacing: -2,
          padding: '20px',
        }}
      >
        Rayrun
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          color: '#fff',
          fontSize: 80,
          fontWeight: 700,
          letterSpacing: -2,
          padding: '20px',
        }}
      >
        {contents.title}
      </div>
    </div>,
    {
      fonts: [
        {
          data: await readFile(join(__dirname, '../fonts/Outfit-Regular.ttf')),
          name: 'Outfit',
          style: 'normal',
          weight: 400,
        },
        {
          data: await readFile(join(__dirname, '../fonts/Outfit-Bold.ttf')),
          name: 'Outfit',
          style: 'normal',
          weight: 700,
        },
      ],
      height: 600,
      width: 1_200,
    },
  );

  const transformer = Transformer.fromSvg(svg);

  return await transformer.png();
};
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but doesn't work for me (so far). It says that it requires an appropriate loader? Am I missing something? Is there a github repo with the code above?

Comment: thanks a lot! I was searching for an example of using custom font with satori for about an hour and a half and this saved me. works like a charm.